# Getting runtime exception when trying to connect with ManagedObjectContext in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I created a Core Data application and I took the .xcdatamodel file from it and added it to another iOS application.  This new application is a SingleView application, and I am now trying to connect to this .xcdatamodel file to run Core Data functions.  What I have done is created a Singleton class through which I call an instance method:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[SingletonDB sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
```

The managedObjectContext method looks like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{

    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    if(context){
        return context;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = nil;

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyTestDatabase" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSLog(@"%@", [objectModel entities]);
 ...
}
```

In the "managedObjectContext" method, for some reason the value for modelURL is nil, and thus causing the RuntimeException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
```

Am I missing a step that is causing this error?  When I select the MyTestDB.xcdatamodel file, I see the full Core Data schema that I created in my previous application, and now for some reason I am unable to read the data.  I have also tried changing the extension from "momd", to "mom", but that only changes the RuntimeException to:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an SQL store with a nil URL.'
```

What might the problem be?

Comment: Hav you verified that `MyTestDatabase.mom` actually exists in the app bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   + (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
    {
        static NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
        if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return managedObjectModel;
        }
        NSString * modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyTestDatabase" ofType:@"momd"];
        managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath]];

        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    +(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator{
        static NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * persistentStoreCoordinator;
        if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSError *error=nil;
        NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyTestDatabase.sqlite"];

        NSURL *storeUrl =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"store url %@",storeUrl);
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);
        }    



        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    +(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        static NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext;
        if(managedObjectContext!=nil){
            return managedObjectContext;
        }
        @try {
            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
            if (coordinator != nil) {
                managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
                [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception occur %@",exception);
        }
        return managedObjectContext;

    }
```